# How to find the difference between 2 files in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

There are 100 files in dir and there are 2 pairs of file.

I want to find the difference between 2 files in shell script

```
File 1: 
Operating System : Windows XP
Operating System : Windows NT
Operating System : Windows 2008

FILE 2: 
Windows XP
Windows NT
Windows2008
```

( e.g Windows 2008 ( file 1 ) and Windows2008 ( file2) ) .

But finally both file dont have any difference.

How to achieve this?

These file in linux host and want to do shell script ?

Comment: This question is very unclear. Is it 100 files or two files you want to compare? What do you mean by "shell script"? This is a Unix term; Windows only has batch, command and PowerShell scripts unless you use a Unix simulation environment like Cygwin.

Comment: in dir there will File1.host.pg1.txt and file1.host.pg2.txt and file1.host2.pg1.txt .... like this

Comment: Where can I get a copy of Microsoft Widnows?  Is that better than Windows?

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: I think the question itself is not related to Windows, it's only an example for his text files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use Perl and `diff`, shall we?  `cut` doesn't quite do the job.  In faithfulness to your original comment, I'm going to look for the word that comes after 'Widnows' in each line of input, and create a new file consisting of only those words.  Then I'm going to diff the files.

Every time I've posted Perl, **every single time**, I've had a swarm of StackOverflowers criticize it.  So, get ready for some bad Perl.  It will probably work.  My reputation can take the downvotes, and I really want to be helpful here.

First, the Perl script (call it `preparse.pl`):

```
my $f = shift @ARGV;
open FILE, "<$f" or die("Couldn't open file!");
while (<FILE>) {
    print "$1\n" if $_ =~ /Widnows(\s?)*?(\S+)\s*/;
}
```

Now, the command you run:

```
preparse.pl file1 > file1.tmp
preparse.pl file2 > file2.tmp
diff file1.tmp file2.tmp
```

Feel free to make this one big Perl script.  Whatever.

Answer (score 2):

The `diff` utility is on most systems, and the `-u` unified output is most popular.

```
$ diff -u file1 file2
--- file1   2010-07-14 02:08:20.000000000 -0700
+++ file2   2010-07-14 02:08:29.000000000 -0700
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
-Operating System : Windows XP
-Operating System : Windows NT
-Operating System : Windows 2008
+Windows XP
+Windows NT
+Windows2008
```

If you want a word-by-word diff instead, you can use less-common tools such as `wdiff`:

```
$ wdiff file1 file2
[-Operating System :-]Windows XP
[-Operating System :-]
Windows NT
[-Operating System : Windows 2008-]
{+Windows2008+}
```

If you want a more visually obvious view of the differences in two files, you can use tools such as [`xxdiff`](http://furius.ca/xxdiff/doc/screenshots/dirindex.html) or
 [`kdiff3`](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/doc/screenshots.html) or similar. (There are a *lot* of three-way-merge graphical diff tools.)

If you want something that might be easier to use programmatically, the `cmp` program can list all the byte dif
ferences in files:

```
$ cmp -l file1 file2
 1 117 127
 2 160 151
 3 145 156
...
```

`cmp` may be more useful on files that are very nearly identical.

Answer (score 1):

The question is too imprecise, but try this:

```
diff <(sed 's/Operating System : //' file1.txt) file2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use diff, diff3 if you are comparing 3 files with each other or vimdiff.